# About how to get the Bitmap from a image or an video image?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

Im a new in android im studying the image bitmap,
please add some info if something im missing..

My Learnings!
1. In decoding a bitmap from a file which is already an image,

```
String pathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/download/" + "ZG4T5vzQSPQ.png";
imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmap(pathName, 100, 120));
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(String pathName, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        android.util.Log.d("calculateInSampleSize()", "H:" + options.outHeight
                + " W:" + options.outWidth);
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2; // 1 = 1 * 2
            }
        }
        android.util.Log.d("calculateInSampleSize()", "inSampleSize:"
                + inSampleSize);
        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

If you want to decode an image to bitmap a single path is needed but
if you want to decode a video and get its videoThumbnail why single path is not
enough? you need to create a videoThumbnail like this!

```
Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(pathName,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Axarydax I think he want to extract Bitmap from an image (which form idk?) or a video (which form idk).

Comment: @shkschneider but his code shows that he's done that, doesn't it?

Comment: yup i already done with my code. I just want to know why android api dont have an api that get directly the VideoThumbnail using only path, but in get image, path only is needed? because if you want to create bitmap in an image path only is needed but in videoThumbnail u need to use the ThumbnailUtils and MediaStore